# Remote Desktop to Windows 10 will not scale font size

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, scaling

I am attempting to remote desktop into Windows 10.  I have adjusted the display size on the actual PC to scale fonts and such to 125%, which is what I had previously set on my WIndows Server 2012R2 box. When I RDP into WIndows 10, however, the font sizes are set back to 100% and not my selected 125%.  Windows Server 2012R2 works properly and the display is scaled as I expected.

What do I need to do to fix this without spending money on a third party tool (option of very last resort)?  It's really hard to read such a small font.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a way to get what I want.  The scaling did nothing.. I could adjust the slider toi "change the size of text...." with zero effect.  I then tried a custom scaling factor... same result, no scaling.  Only thing I found was the option to "change only the text size"... set all 6 items from 9 to 11.  Not sure which one actually did the trick but the fonts are now larger.  Well, most are.  The font in the Display control panel item is still small... is there a way to generically increase the size of the dialog fonts?

Doesn't answer the question though... why won't the scaling work?